# OpenPyXL Set Worksheet Formula and Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to create an Excel workbook in Python that includes formulas, and want to parse the workbook later without needing to open it in Excel first to evaluate the formula.  E.g., I have a formula with a known computation result, and want to store both the formula and its resulting value using OpenPyXL.

How can I accomplish this with OpenPyXL?

E.g., I want to code the following worksheet:

| Value | Log(10) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 (=LOG10(A2)) |
| 10 | 1 (=LOG10(A3)) |

The code I was expecting to write to produce this is something like the following:

```
import math
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.cell(1, 1).value = 'Value'
ws.cell(1, 2).value = 'Log(10)'

for row, i in enumerate([1, 10], start = 2):
    ws.cell(row, 1).value = i
    formulaCell = ws.cell(row, 2)
    # What do I have to assign here in order to be able to read both the formula and value later?
    formulaCell.value = math.log10(i)
    formulaCell.formula = f'=LOG10(A{row})'

wbName = 'test.xlsx'
wb.save(wbName)

# Read the value and formula back in
wb_data     = load_workbook(wbName, data_only = True)
wb_formulas = load_workbook(wbName, data_only = False)

# The following is expected to print:
# 0
# =LOG10(A2)
print(wb_data['B2'].value)
print(wb_formulas['B2'].value)
```

Comment: There is no attribute 'formula' for a cell in Openpyxl. The difference between accessing the Value or Formula of a cell is determined by the 'data_only' parameter. When 'data_only=True' is used that workbook does not know anything about formulas in any cell so if it's then saved the formulas will be replaced by the values, (unless your code actually writes formula(s) to cell(s) before saving.

Comment: Another module like Xlwings will have both 'value' and 'formula' attributes for a cell. But then, it uses Excel and evaluates the formula.

Comment: Openpyxl avoids confusion and potential errors by forcing you to choose. Xlsxwriter will let you write both a formula and its notional value.

Comment: OpenPyXL, which requires loading the same Excel file twice, then pass two copies of the same workbook/worksheet/row/cell to EVERY function in an application to parse data/formulas out of an Excel file, is not would I would label as the "avoids confusion" approach.  Seems much less confusing to me had the implementation just provided a `formula` member.  Thank you all for confirming this is a limitation of the OpenPyXL implementation, though.